# RegEx conditional based on which letter

Tags: c#, regex

I have an `if` statement that I am trying to condense down into a regex statement.  The `if` statement is the following:

```
 string degree = "21S"
 if (degree != "" && 
     Convert.ToInt32(degree) > 9 && 
     TChr == "N" || 
    degree != "" && 
    Convert.ToInt32(degree) > 41 && TChr == "S")
```

The string will always be a number and either an `S` or `N` (north/south). If it is a `N`, the number must be between `1-9`, if it is an `S`, the range is `1-41`.

I have been trying a range with a conditional:

```
^(?(/dN)[1-9]N|[1-51]S)$
```

However, it is not catching anything, so I assume I am going about it the wrong way.

Comment: The if statement looks circumspect where the `||` or is...can you fix the logic? Is that a typo?

Comment: It was copied out of working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b(?:[1-9]N|(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[01])S)\b

var pattern = @"\b(?:[1-9]N|(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[01])S)\b";
```

Here is the [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb(%3f%3a%5b1-9%5dN%7c(%3f%3a%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b1-3%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c4%5b01%5d)S)%5cb&i=0N%0d%0a1N%0d%0a2N%0d%0a3N%0d%0a4N%0d%0a5N%0d%0a6N%0d%0a7N%0d%0a7N%0d%0a8N%0d%0a9N%0d%0a10N%0d%0a0S%0d%0a1S%0d%0a2S%0d%0a3S%0d%0a4S%0d%0a5S%0d%0a6S%0d%0a7S%0d%0a8S%0d%0a9S%0d%0a10S%0d%0a11S%0d%0a20S%0d%0a21S%0d%0a29S%0d%0a30S%0d%0a31S%0d%0a40S%0d%0a41S%0d%0a42S).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Regex isn't the best tool for this job, because it's difficult to check integer ranges with a regex.

Unless you really have to use regular expressions, I'd just clean up what you have a little. It's much more readable code than a regex that does the same thing.

```
string input = "21S";
char direction = input.Last();
int degree = int.Parse(input.Trim('N', 'S'));
bool valid = ((direction == 'N' && degree >= 1 && degree <= 9) ||
              (direction == 'S' && degree >= 1 && degree <= 41);
```

Comment: I agree, though the pjt mgr specifically wants regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were trying for this:

```
^(?(?=\dN)[1-9]N|(?:4[01]|[1-3][0-9]|[1-9])S)$
```

...but you don't really need a conditional for this task.   This works just fine:

```
^(?:[1-9]N|(?:4[01]|[1-3][0-9]|[1-9])S)$
```

Also, you can't match *numbers* with regexes (i.e., by their numerical values).  Letters, digits, punctuation or whatever, they're all just characters.